# Grouping and moving guides in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Is it possible to move a bunch of guides together as a group in Inkscape?

I want to move all objects drawn on a page along with the guides that were used for drawing them to another part of the page. What would be the best way for achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw lines along your guides, move the lines as a part of your drawing, but grouped or in different layer to keep them easily accessible. The lines must be perfectly straight (click-only) 2 node paths.

After moving make a copy of the line set and convert the lines to guides with Object > Objects to guides. They can be a group, but the guides will be separate.

Keep, but hide the line set in case you need it later elsewhere or you must restore an accidentally destroyed guide.

ADD: If you want to get rid of no more needed guides you cannot select them as a group. You can make one at a time active by pointing it with the mouse, press DEL to kill it. Even XML code panel allows you to select only one guide at a time.

NOTE: I am not a programmer so I don't know is it possible to create working guide groups in the XML code panel.

You can delete ALL guides with extension Render > Guides Creator:

[image]

Let it divide your artboard to one row and one column and let it delete existing guides. No new guides will appear. If you have line groups for fast guide creation you do not lose much by deleting all guides.

Comment: But, how do we delete the previous group of guides?

Comment: @saraf the answer is augmented.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what else is on your page, another approach is to move the page relative to the drawing and guides, rather than vice versa.

1. Create a rectangle (<kbd>F4</kbd>) of the appropriate size (use the snap tools to snap to the existing page margins, or type the dimensions, which are listed in "Document Properties") at the location that you would like the new page to be.
2. With the rectangle still selected, open **Document Properties** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and select "Resize to content"

[image: Resize to content]

Now the page has been moved, but the guides remain in place.  Delete your placeholder rectangle and move any other content to its original position.